# Android translate a image based on the scale of another

Tags: android, android-layout, scale

I have this application where there are 2 ImageViews, one is acting like a background, the other is a small image that is positioned on the background image and acts like a say marker on the map and needs to stay in position related to the background image.

So making this happen on drag is easy, but what I need is to maintains the small image's relative position to the background image when the user zooms the background image, here is the code so far (lampMatrix and lampStart are the matrix and PointF that are used for the smaller image):

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
      WrapMotionEvent event = WrapMotionEvent.wrap(rawEvent);
      // ...
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

         savedLampMatrix.set(lampMatrix);
         lampStart.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
         break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);

            lampMatrix.set(savedLampMatrix);
            lampMatrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - lampStart.x, event.getY() - lampStart.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageMatrix(lampMatrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }
```